# records from a time period and one additional in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple MySQL table which contains time-value pairs.

I need to get items from the last week (or any period) and one additional record, as  i want to draw a chart from the data and need to know the last value before the 1 week period,so the beginning of the chart will not be empty. (items are very rare, it's like 1-2 records per day)

i tried something like this, but it seems this is completely wrong syntax:

```
SELECT * from mytable ORDER BY Time desc 
LIMIT (SELECT count(*) from mytable WHERE Time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)+1;
```

table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE mytable ( 
Time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
Value double DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Time) );
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: Whence does the extra one record come?  From before or after the range?

Comment: as i want to get data from the last week, the additional record must be the last before the period.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `Time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Time`)

Comment: Add that to your question, here in the comments it's unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You cannot do that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

What you can do is selecting the rows in the desired interval and unite them with the first one outside

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   Time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   Time <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
ORDER BY Time desc
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: this will return only 1 record.. but after i put the 2nd select in brackets, it works fine... thanks..